# Data Scraping and Sequencing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

```
$('#InputBox').val("mscu8340256");
$("#search").trigger('click');
var a=$(".alt1").html();
alert(a);
```

I am executing this code in the console of Google Chrome, but the alert box says `undefined`. I was expecting the result:

```
<td class="tooltipB" title="">ASHDOD, IL</td><td>Discharged</td><td>30/11/2013</td><td>MSC ANTONIA</td><td>AO346A</td>
```

I also tried a callback function like this:

```
$('#InputBox').val("mscu8340256");
$("#search").trigger('click',function(){
var a=$(".alt1").html();
alert(a);
});
```

but this doesn’t work either.

But when I execute

```
$('#InputBox').val("mscu8340256");
$("#search").trigger('click');
```

and then

```
var a=$(".alt1").html();
alert(a);
```

it shows the result.

How do I execute all the code together, as I want to run this code on `document.ready`?

[Demo](http://tracking.mscgva.ch/msctracking.php).

Comment: looks like a trigger handler registered somewhere else is loading the content using a async operation

Comment: So what's the solution?